# How to check dict of a list is empty?

Tags: python, dictionary

The idea is to check whether the following dict inside list inside dict is empty or not.

For example, the following  dict

```
expected_false={"all_dict": [{"A": [1], "B": [], "C": [], "D": []}]}
```

should return  empty to be false as the key 'A' has a value of 1.

whereas, the following should return empty to be true

```
expected_empty={"all_dict": [{"A": [], "B": [], "C": [], "D": []}]}
```

I tried the following code, but it give different than what I have in mind.

```
all(not d for d in expected_true['all_dict'][0])
```

Comment: You are checking the truth values of the keys, not the values.

Comment: .. also, this code is error prone for cases where the values are anything else except lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
any(len(item) for item in expected_true['all_dict'][0].values())
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
print(not any(len(expected_false['all_dict'][x]) > 0 for x in expected_false['all_dict']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are set of key-value pairs.
Pseudo-code:

```
-Get value of 'all_dict' key inside of dictionary that named {expected_false}
-That 'all_dict' key has a value which is a list that contains only one item (which is an another dictionary)
-To address list item : ['all_dict'][0] (we reached first list item, which is a dictionary)
-Use dict.values() method to get all values of keys innermost dictionary
-And each of these values are also list by itself

expected_false['all_dict'][0].values()
```

Therefore the code above returns lists. And check everylist if there is any item in it. Then print result.

```
expected_false={"all_dict": [{"A": [1], "B": [], "C": [], "D": []}]}
for item in expected_false['all_dict'][0].values():
    if len(item)!=0:
        a=any(item)
        print(a)
```

Comment: add context so we can learn and to prevent down-voting or removal of question. EoR.

Comment: i am not the owner of question, but added explanation of code anyway

Comment: sharp.. should have been "answer" ;-)